# Call JFace ComboViewer setComparator() upon open

Tags: java, swt, listener, jface

I am stuck with a SWT problem. I want to postpone the creation of a ViewerComparator class to the point a user actually wants to select an item from the ComboViewer. In my use case the Comparator is a pretty complex beast that uses a lot of resources. The user usually does not need to actually open the CombiViewer, so I thought I could save computing time by deferring the creation of the Comparator to the moment when it is really needed.

Here is what I tried:

```
comboViewer1.addOpenListener(new IOpenListener(){

    @Override
    public void open(OpenEvent event) {

        if (comboViewer1.getComparator() == null){
            comboViewer1.setComparator(new ViewerComp(transientModelThing.getComRef()));
        }
    }
});
```

I am not very familiar with SWT and JFace. But in the debugger I see that this open method is NEVER called. I expected it to be called when the user tried to fold out the combo box.

No ideas to why the listener is not working? A postSelectionListener that I register much the same way functions flawlessly. comboViewer1 and transientModelThing are a public globals. ViewerComp is my private class that implements this complex Comparator.

Comment: So, it's the `open` method that is not called, not just the `if` part that isn't executed?

Comment: `IOpenListener` is called when an entry in the list is double clicked (or single clicked depending on the open strategy). It is not called when the Combo viewer opens the drop down list.

Comment: @greg-449, THX so what type of listener would I need? There should be a hook that can i use just before the comboviewer is expanded.

Comment: There is no specific event, this question has some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429895/how-to-update-the-list-of-items-in-the-swt-combo-box

Comment: @Baz, yes correct. The open is not called. It seems i use the wrong type of Listener

Answer (score 0):

In the good tradition of answering own questions if they are solved, I put here my solution:

```
comboViewer1.getControl().addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, new Listener(){

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        if (comboViewer1.getComparator() == null){
            comboViewer1.setComparator(new ViewerComp(transientModelThing.getComRef()));
        }
    }
});
```

I used the `SWT.MouseEnter` event for now. This is of course not exactly what I wanted, but it is close enough.

@greg-449 Thx for the input!

Comment: Wouldn't `SWT.MouseDown` be the better solution?

Comment: I tried both. ```MouseDown``` is not working for that purpose.

Comment: Which version of SWT are you using? According to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=273850), it should be working.