# Need to create SWT Combo items when they are about to viewed

Tags: java, eclipse, events, combobox, swt

I have a few Combo's in an eclipse plugin that I need to create dynamically when the combo is about to be opened. I need this as system state can change and I want the combo items to reflect that. The changes are unrelated to eclipse, so I cannot be notified about them.

I can easily do that with the focusGained method of the focusListener, but that only happens when the focus is gained after it was lost. I want the items to be updated ***every time*** the user clicks on the combo, even without the mouse moves out of focus or clicks elsewhere.

I tried also the mouseDown event, but then the combo gets an ugly scrollbar because it was drawn before I added the items.

Any idea on what I should use for this?

Thanks in advance, Oren

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429895/how-to-update-the-list-of-items-in-the-swt-combo-box)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem is, that the layout of the parent of the `Combo` needs to layout after you added the items to display in the correct size.

When you do that, however, the `Combo` closes. You can programmatically open it again, but this doesn't look very nice (since it flashes open, then closes, then opens again).

It is however, the best solution I can think of right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ToolBar bar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.NONE);
    bar.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Combo combo = new Combo(bar, SWT.READ_ONLY);

    Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            combo.removeAll();

            combo.add("A");
            combo.add("B");
            combo.add("C");

            combo.getParent().layout();
            combo.setListVisible(true);
        }
    };

    combo.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and I still get the scroll which I tried to avoid. No flashes though...

Comment: @OrenSarid Does the parent of the `Combo` have a layout or are you setting the size manually?

Comment: I am not setting it manually, but the combo is a menu contribution and resides in a toolbar, if it helps

Comment: @OrenSarid Updated my code to use a `ToolBar` (can't test it in an RCP just now). Can you test if this exact code (not your changed code) works for you? If not, please post what OS you're using and which version of SWT.

Comment: With your code as stand alone there are no issues. But when using it on an eclipse toolbar I get the scrollbar.

Comment: @OrenSarid I'm afraid I can't help you then.